# How to import xlsx file into html, search items(using a code number) into this and create a pdf with table and searched files

Tags: html, excel

Hi everyones i need to import xlsx file into html, search items(using a code number)by form into this and create a pdf with table and searched files. am i need a db? can i do it in local?

Comment: have you tried save as html inside excel?

Comment: of course but i have a list of items in an excel file. i have various orders. based on a single order i need to select every item(every item has a code, description, number of pieces and price) from excel with item's code. so in the end i should have a table with selected items and i will convert to pdf

Comment: So basically you want to use the excel file as a database and then create a PDF? I am thinking that you can almost do that with [tag:vba] and [tag:excel] alone.